# Drag and drop limit to angle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math

**Background**
I have a Google Maps application in which a person is to draw a rectangle in as few clicks as possible, the solution is to draw a line at the centre and expand outwards by clicking and dragging the edges.

**Problem**
I know the angle between the two lat/longs on the map that form the line I mentioned above so I can draw a rectangle around that line, easy. Knowing the angle of the original line I need to limit the dragging of the lines parallel to the original to the same angle but I don't know where to start with that, how do I limit the dragging of those two lines so that they remain parallel at all times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot simple geometry/algebra.. the way to do this would be to use the standard distance formula `D = SQRT((x1 - x2)² + (y1 - y2)²)` on the two vertices that make the line and then transform those coordinates by the below [orthogonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)

`| 0 -1 | -> x axis
| 1  0  | -> y axis`

You also need to use the standard distance formula to get the distance between the mouse and the old line to calculate what `OFFSET` might equal.

It's worth noting that you need to use the Google Maps geometry library for this and to convert each `LatLng` pair into a `Point` before calculating and then converting back to `LatLng` when you're ready to draw the lines.

`from.x = x1 + OFFSET * (y2 - y1) / D
from.y = y1 + OFFSET * (x1 - x2) / D
to.x   = x2 + OFFSET * (y2 - y1) / D
to.y   = y2 + OFFSET * (x1 - x2) / D`